# QuickBlox iOS SDK filter QBCOCustomObjects by child collection with a given key?

Tags: ios, quickblox

Ex. There are 2 entities: "Parent" -->> "Child" with one-to-many relation.
"Child" has property NSString *myKey.
QuickBlox documentation provides an examples about relations between different QBCOCustomObject [(QuickBlox: Get Related Records)](http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Get_related_records) but only for simple case: how to get "Child" instances with given "Parent" instance.

Is any possibilities to obtain all "Parents" associated with a "Childs" where every "Child" instances have a given "myKey" with one request?
Or I have to use two separate requests for each entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give all Children for particular Parent:

```
https://api.quickblox.com/data/Child?_parent_id=<your_Parent_class_instance_id>
```

To give all 'Parents' ids associated with a "Childs" where every "Child" instances have a given "myKey":

```
https://api.quickblox.com/data/Child?myKey=<some_value>
```

then each Child has _parent_id field

Comment: I wish I could make only one request to the API to get "Parent" collection :(
Get all "Parent" IDs is quite simple because child entity has "_parent_id" field.
Hope to find it in future API